# Get html button/drop down text from c# code

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html

I am wondering how I can grab the text from my HTML button/dropdown menu in c#? With the asp.net dropdownlist I was able to do string text = dropdownlist.Value; But it doesnt seem to be as simple, or maybe it is, with a different type of dropdown. I couldnt use the asp drop down list because it didnt act as a button and a drop down menu. The functions below are for changing the text from the default "Advanced" to the selected item text by the user. After the user changes the buttons text, I want to grab that text and use it as a condition for a sqlbuild.where clause. Also the text of the updated button should remain after the search button is clicked. With the asp drop down list the value remained after the refresh but for some reason when I search when the updated drop down menu, the change is wiped after selecting submit

```
Something like this is what i had in mind to do:
// get advancedsearch value
string selectedTxt = AdvancedSearch.value;
//filter on selected value
if (selectedTxt == "item1")
{
    sqlbuilder.where = ("input1@");
}
else if (selectedTxt == "item2")
{
   sqlbuild.where = ("input2@");
etc

        // container for button/dropdown menu
        <div class="container">
                <div class="row buffer">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ">
                            <div class="input-group" role="group" >
                                <div class="input-group-btn" role="group">
                                <asp:Button runat="server" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" id="AdvancedSearch" data-toggle="dropdown" OnClientClick="AdvancedSubmit();" style="background-color:#718CA1;color:#FFF;" Text="Advanced:" />
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" runat="server" id="dropdown" style="background-color:#718CA1;color:#FFF;">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-value="asset">item1</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-value="building">item2</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-value="astmgrbems">item3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-center">
                            <div class="input-group" role="group">
                                <input type="text" id="InquiryInput2" onblur="javascript:removeSpaces()" style="display:none" runat="server" class="form-control" Width="280px" />
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                </div>
```

*EDIT* - Realize I forgot to add functions if that helps

function AdvancedSubmit() {
             var obj = document.getElementById('<%=InquiryInput2.ClientID%>');

```
         if (obj.style.display == 'none') {
             obj.style.display = 'block';
         }
     };
     $(function () {
         $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
             var selText = $(this).text();
             /* $(".btn btn-secondary").html(selText);*/
             alert(selText);
             document.getElementById('<%=AdvancedSearch.ClientID%>').value = selText;
         })
     });
```

Comment: Looks like you're using a `Text` attribute; would it not be `button.Text`?

Comment: Is the button text actually changing on the page? If so, this wouldn't be posted back with the form. Maybe you could add a hidden field for this, and change that value at the same time as the button's value?

Comment: @Whothehellisthat yes the button text is actually changing on the page via the function I just pasted. Sorry forgot to add it in originally even though I mentioned it. So you're saying I can add a hidden field on the front end that captures the html selText change and then use that as a filter on the c# side?

Comment: @Whothehellisthat I am using the Text attribute for the  text box InquiryInput2 that appears after the Advanced search button is clicked. Defaults to hidden.

Comment: Yeah. It's been a while since I c#-ed it up, but just add an asp hidden field. Then in the javascript set that field's value as well as the button's value. That way it'll be posted back to the server when the form is submitted.

Comment: This worked man. Much appreciated. How can I give you answer credit since you just commented?

Comment: I've added an answer with the same content. You can approve that if you like. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an ASP hidden field. Then in the javascript set that field's value as well as the button's value. That way it'll be posted back to the server when the form is submitted.